# Why Cassandra cluster need synchronized clocks between nodes?

Tags: cassandra

In the [introduction course of Cassandra DataStax](https://academy.datastax.com/courses) they say that all of  the clocks of a Cassandra cluster nodes, have to be synchronized, in order to prevent READ queries to 'old' data.

If one or more nodes are down they can not get updates, but as soon as they back up again - they would update and there is no problem...

So, why Cassandra cluster need synchronized clocks between nodes?

Comment: My thought would be that Synchronisation relies on knowing the time that changes were made. If a node knows it synchronised at a given time, then another node writes data with an earlier time-stamp the first node will not know it needs to resync that data. People using that first node will then read old data. I am not sure why a node being down comes into this. If it's down no-one can make changes on it that the others would need to sync. When it comes back up it will know when it last synced and will sync to the others based on their changes since then.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general it is always a good idea to keep your server clocks in sync, but a  primary reason why clock sync is needed between nodes is because Cassandra uses a concept called 'Last Write Wins' to resolve conflicts and determine which mutation represents the most correct up-to date state of data.  This is explained in [Why cassandra doesn't need vector clocks](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/why-cassandra-doesnt-need-vector-clocks).

Whenever you 'mutate' (write or delete) column(s) in cassandra a timestamp is assigned by the coordinator handling your request.  That timestamp is written with the column value in a cell.

When a read request occurs, cassandra builds your results finding the mutations for your query criteria and when it sees multiple cells representing the same column it will pick the one with the most recent timestamp (The read path is more involved than this but that is all you need to know in this context).

Things start to become problematic when your nodes' clocks become out of sync.  As I mentioned, the coordinator node handling your request assigns the timestamp.  If you do multiple mutations to the same column and different coordinators are assigned, you can create some situations where writes that happened in the past are returned instead of the most recent one.

Here is a basic scenario that describes that:

Assume we have a 2 node cluster with nodes A and B.   Lets assume an initial state where A is at time `t10` and B is at time `t5`.

1. User executes `DELETE C FROM tbl WHERE key=5`.  Node A coordinates the request and it is assigned timestamp `t10`.
2. A second passes and a User executes `UPDATE tbl SET C='data' where key=5`.  Node B coordinates the request and it is assigned timestamp `t6`.
3. User executes the query `SELECT C from tbl where key=5`.    Because the `DELETE` from Step 1 has a more recent timestamp (`t10 > t6`), no results are returned.

Note that newer versions of the datastax drivers will start defaulting to use Client Timestamps to have your client application generate and assign timestamps to requests instead of relying on the C* nodes to assign them.  datastax java-driver as of 3.0 now defaults to client timestamps (read more about there in ['Client-side generation'](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/query_timestamps/#client-side-generation)).  This is very nice if all requests come from the same client,  however if you have multiple applications writing to cassandra you now have to worry about keeping your client clocks in sync.

Comment: Great answer, Thank you!

Comment: Nice explanation. Let us consider I am having 4 nodes in a cluster in Amazon EC2 within a single DC. I have configured snitch as SimpleSnitch. I didn't used any client side time stamp mechanism (By assuming the server itself should handle the time) and I didn't used any NTP services, But by default all the 4 EC2 instance will have same time. Will this scenario will affect data consistency?

Comment: Clocks are known to drift, especially in virtualized environments like EC2 (see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/why-is-my-ec2-servers-time-off-by-10-seconds-every-day).  So even if your clocks are in sync now, you will likely face the same issues if you do not use ntpd to sync your clocks.

Comment: Thanks Andy, could you please help answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416917/do-i-need-clock-synchronization-in-cassandra-if-only-one-client-writes-to-cluste

Comment: @RadaReshef That's why Cassandra is probably most suited for scenarios that mainly store immutable data. For frequent updates something with vector clocks would be more appropriate

Comment: You could also consider using Lightweight Transactions (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) which has better semantics around timestamps, however you'll pay a performance cost.  That being said you will also pay a performance cost with a DB-implementation using vector clocks, but cost will vary depending on the implementation.