# Does Cassandra need all the servers to have the same time?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have a .NET application on a Windows machine and a Cassandra database on a Linux (CentOS) server. The Windows machine **might be with a couple of seconds in the past** sometimes and when that thing happens, the deletes or updates queries does not take effect.

Does Cassandra require all servers to have the same time? Does the Cassandra driver send my query with timestamp? (I just write simple delete or update query, with not timestamp or TTL).

Update: I use the [Datastax C# driver](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client timestamps are used to order mutation operations relative to each other.

The [DataStax C# driver uses a generator to create them](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/latest/features/query-timestamps/), it's important for all the hosts running the client drivers (origin of the execution request) to have clocks in sync with each other.

Comment: @jorgebgthank you very much for your response. From the article above I understand that the driver sends the query with a timestamp. However, if I have only a single server (my .NET app) and only a single Cassandra database. It it normal for the problem to occur if these two are out of sync?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, its the requests with a timestamp. It won't be a problem if client and server clocks are out of sync, as timestamps are used to order mutations relative to each other, but the source of those mutations will be a single client instance.

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra operates on the "last write wins" principle. The system time is therefore critically important in determining which writes succeed. Google for "cassandra time synchronization" to find [results like this](https://blog.rapid7.com/2014/03/14/synchronizing-clocks-in-a-cassandra-cluster-pt-1-the-problem/) and [this](https://blog.rapid7.com/2014/03/17/synchronizing-clocks-in-a-cassandra-cluster-pt-2-solutions/) which explain why time synchronization is important and suggests a method to solve the problem utilizing an internal NTP pool. The articles specifically refer to AWS architecture, but the principals apply to any cassandra installation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have searched by your terms and found another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898693/why-cassandra-cluster-need-synchronized-clocks-between-nodes

But it says that the cluster syncronizes the clocks by itself. So I don't understand. This problem was in cassandra pre 3.0 or is it still in 3.0?

Comment: Time synchronization is an issue with every Cassandra version. NTP (network time protocol) daemon needs to be installed on every node, but the default settings are not enough. The nodes do not synchronize the clocks by themselves. NTP must be configured properly. Best practice is to create an NTP pool inside your network. This pool synchronized to an external pool, and then the ntp daemons on your cassandra nodes synchronize to your internal pool as explained in the second link in my post.

Comment: Do you know if this issue happens also with the driver that it is connecting to the cluster?

Comment: sorry, I'm more of a cassandra administrator, not a developer, so I can't answer for sure. Maybe someone else knows?